# Accessing navigationBarController from another class in swift

Tags: swift, navigationbar

I want to access my navigation bar in class MyNavigationBarController.swift from my main class HomeController. This is due to the fact that I am reusing the navigation bar in different view controllers and I want to reduce redundancies at that point. It works fine when I integrate the function in HomeController.swift.

However, when I make the navigation class a separate one, no navigation bar is shown anymore when starting the simulator.

I feel like the problem lies in "self.view" but I cannot figure out how to fix this.

**Swift 4**

**HomeController.swift**

```
class HomeController: UIViewController {

let myNavigator = MyNavigationBarController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // load navigation bar
    myNavigator.setNavigationBar()
}
```

**MyNavigationBarController.swift**

```
class MyNavigationBarController: UINavigationController {

let navBar = UINavigationBar()

func setNavigationBar() {
    navBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let navItem = UINavigationItem(title: "")
    let statusItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Status", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(status))

    navItem.rightBarButtonItem = statusItem

    navBar.setItems([navItem], animated: false)

    self.view.addSubview(navBar)
}

@objc func status() {
    print("hello")
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. The problem is `self.view`. You need to add it to the controller's view. You can change your function, like this:

```
func setNavigationBarInView(_ view:UIView) {
    navBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let navItem = UINavigationItem(title: "")
    let statusItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Status", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(status))

    navItem.rightBarButtonItem = statusItem

    navBar.setItems([navItem], animated: false)

    view.addSubview(navBar)
}
```

And then:

```
myNavigator.setNavigationBarInView(view)
```